# Find a div based on class, check for list, if none, remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the class of "js" from the UL class if the UL does not contain a LI within. 
This is what I have and cannot get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: This is not a code mill. Have you tried anything and it not work? You're going to be using the jQuery has(), hide(), and removeClass() functions, I can tell you that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$.each($('.globalNavChild'), function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.find('li').length) {
        $this.removeClass('js').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y95ch/)**

Comment: How can I remove the class children as well? I tried $this.find('.children.js').removeClass('children');

Comment: @user3290938 You need `$this.prev().removeClass('children js')` since anchor is the previous element of your `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var foo = $('ul.js');
if(foo.length > 0 && foo.find('li').length == 0){
   foo.removeClass('js').hide();
}
```

Comment: Call me petty, but if you can't proof-read your answer enough to ensure the quote-count is correct, it deserves a down-vote.

Comment: Down-vote revoked. Always check your answer before hitting post!

Answer (score 0):

You have to find such `ul` elements which don't  (`:not` selector in jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ ) have ( `:has` selector in jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) any LI as children.

When you have found them, you can `.removeClass` (https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to remove the unneeded class and then `.addClass` (https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add the one you need.